# How to filter and operation using network protocol in Tile38

Tags: java, curl, geofence, tile38

I want to query my result with and operation, in my cli the command is goes fine but if i try to make client with http error invalid argument '&&' has occured.
Please can anyone know how to format text first, this is my example curl request?

CLI Command :
within evidence where 'timestamp >= 1654128000 && timestamp <= 1658361600' get areas indonesia-aceh

Curl :
`curl --location 'localhost:9851' \ --header 'Content-Type: text/plain' \ --data 'within evidence where '\''timestamp >= 1654128000 && timestamp <= 1658361600'\'' get areas indonesia-aceh'`

To successfully make request in Tile38

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be an issue with the Tile 38 multiple filter option when making a HTTP call, instead of using the && operator when using the curl command, chain the WHERE for multiple options

For example: the document says to use the command like `curl --data "SCAN geo=1 WHERE properties.val == 4 && properties.name == count_three" localhost:9851`

But this will throw `{"ok":false,"err":"invalid argument '&&'","elapsed":"64.9µs"}`

Instead use `curl --data "SCAN geo=1 WHERE properties.val == 4 WHERE properties.name == count_three" localhost:9851` to make it work

This will only be a workaround and not a proper way, as this only works when you want to apply AND condition